# open up WAMP server to other computers

Tags: php, apache, public

For some reason, the sites that I put up on my WAMP installation can only be reached by computers on the same network. What I want to do is to open it all up so that everyone can access it. Here is my config:

```
ServerSignature On
ServerTokens Full

ServerRoot "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9"

Define APACHE24 Apache2.4

Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80

LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php5apache2_4.dll"

<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>


ServerAdmin admin@example.com

ServerName localhost:80

HostnameLookups Off

DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride all


Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/access.log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3

</IfModule>

EnableSendfile off

AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none

Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

Include "c:/wamp/alias/*"
```

Comment: you need to take a look in DNS | FIREWALL | ROUTING then it will be work

Comment: canyouseeme.org and make sure your port 80 is visible.

Comment: Seems like a bad idea. Your ISP probably specifically disallows this, your open yourself up to all sorts of security issues, and rented server space is dirt cheap.

Comment: I don't have much of a choice though - I need to access data from an odbc connection on our lan and use it in a report i've made in php.

Answer (score 0):

change the port setting in firewall and confirm your ip is static and check Apache configuration finally make wamp online

Comment: I tried disabling the firewall for 5 min and I still can't get it to work, so it's not a firewall issue.